# Problems installing ffmpeg on Mac OS X 10.11.6 El Capitan

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, build, terminal, osx-elcapitan

I tried installing it using homebrew and also tried to clone but it always ends up failing building. I don't find the cause. Is it because of my operating system being old?

[homebrew install fail screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSmWR.png)

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Although you found a solution using a really old FFmpeg I don't recommend using it. You're missing out on bug fixes, security fixes, features, and thousands of updates.

It appears you got FFmpeg 4.1.4 from [evermeet](https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/) to work. I recommend using that. All you have to do is uninstall the old homebrew version and move `ffmpeg` from evermeet to a directory in your [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)), such as `/usr/local/bin`. Even better is to download a more recent version such as 4.2.2 or the git "snapshot".

Answer (score 0):

Could you also post a screenshot of the error that home-brew gives you when trying to install that way?

In the meantime, I can tell that you have downloaded the latest version of FFmpeg. If you believe it might be because your OS is old, you could try downloading an older branch of the software. Try:

`brew install ffmpeg@2.8` for example

And, in your screenshot, you seem to be running FFmpeg off of the mounted volume. Have you tried moving this file to somewhere that's on your $PATH?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried donwloading an older ffmpeg as you said and tried the script you told as an example and it worked!

Comment: What version did you get going?  Please post a solution as I'm looking for the same.